# Extract raster value based on list of coordinates - spTransform?

Tags: r, coordinates, raster, r-raster, r-sp

I wish to extract raster values based on a list of coordinates. I’ve found online some scripts that include coordinates(), SpatialPoints(), crs() and spTransform() and other that don’t. Could someone kindly explain if script 1 or script 2 is correct and why? Thank you very much!

SCRIPT 1

```
sites <- read.csv("df.csv")
coordinates(sites)= ~ Longitude+ Latitude 
mypoints = SpatialPoints(sites,proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
myproj = CRS(myraster)
points.proj = spTransform(mypoints, myproj)
myvalues = extract(myraster, points.proj)
```

SCRIPT 2

```
sites <- read.csv("df.csv")
myvalues = extract(myraster, cbind(sites$Longitude, y=sites$Latitude), df=TRUE, method='simple', cellnumbers=T)
```

Comment: can you please paste in the results of `head(sites)` so we can see the types and structure of the `.csv` data you're starting with?

Comment: Next time please include some example data like I do in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either could be correct. With RasterLayer `r` and data.frame `sites` you can do

```
v <- extract(r, sites[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")])
```

Under the assumption that "Longitude" and "Latitude" are variables in `sites`.

However that only works when `r` also has a ("Longitude", "Latitude") coordinate reference system. That may not be the case. Consider this RasterLayer

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
r

#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 115, 80, 9200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 40, 40  (x, y)
#extent     : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +no_defs 
#source     : C:/soft/R/R-3.6.1/library/raster/external/test.grd 
#names      : test 
#values     : 128.434, 1805.78  (min, max)
```

The `crs` is "sterea ..." and the extent  "178400, 181600, ...) shows that the coordinates are clearly not longitude and latitude (they are expressed in meters away from the origin of the crs.)

In this case, you might have a point in the area covered by `r`

```
site <- data.frame(Longitude=5.745039, Latitude=50.96254)
```

But `extract` returns `NA` because the crs do not match

```
extract(r, site)
#     [,1]
#[1,]   NA
```

So we do

```
pts <- SpatialPoints(site)
crs(pts) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
rcrs <- crs(r)
ptrans <- spTransform(pts, rcrs)
```

And now it works

```
extract(r, ptrans)
#1529.66
```